# Trying to understand why GROUP BY and HAVING yields different output when compared to WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that attempt to return all origin cities with flights less than 3 hours (180 minutes)

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.origin_city AS city, MAX(F.actual_time) AS max_time
FROM FLIGHTS F
GROUP BY F.origin_city
HAVING MAX(F.actual_time) < 180
ORDER BY F.origin_city


SELECT DISTINCT F.origin_city AS city, MAX(F.actual_time) AS max_time
FROM FLIGHTS F
WHERE F.actual_time < 180
GROUP BY F.origin_city
ORDER BY F.origin_city
```

For the first query, the first 10 rows (total of 109 rows returned) it returns are:

| city | max_time |
| --- | --- |
| Aberdeen SD | 106 |
| Abilene TX | 111 |
| Alpena MI | 80 |
| Ashland WV | 84 |
| Augusta GA | 176 |
| Barrow AK | 118 |
| Beaumont/Port Arthur TX | 102 |
| Bemidji MN | 104 |
| Bethel AK | 95 |
| Binghamton NY | 132 |

The second query's first 10 rows (total of 325 rows returned) are:

| city | max_time |
| --- | --- |
| Aberdeen SD | 106 |
| Abilene TX | 111 |
| Adak Island AK | 165 |
| Aguadilla PR | 177 |
| Akron OH | 179 |
| Albany GA | 111 |
| Albany NY | 179 |
| Albuquerque NM | 179 |
| Alexandria LA | 179 |
| Allentown/Bethlehem/Easton PA | 177 |

The first query is filtering for the condition before grouping, whereas the second query is filtering for the condition after grouping. However, why does the first query yield fewer rows than the second query's output?

Comment: Stop throwing DISTINCT into a query for no reason. GROUP BY clause will guarantee you have one row per set of grouped columns. DISTINCT serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 3):

The first query shows the cities having MAX(actual_time) < 180

```
HAVING MAX(F.actual_time) < 180
```

whereas second query shows just the cities with actual time < 180

```
WHERE F.actual_time < 180
```

Let's say there is a following data in your table
some_city: 90
some_city: 200
some_city: 300

The first query will get the max value (which is 300) and won't show it in the output. Meanwhile the second query will output the line "some_city: 90" as it satistfies the where-condition

Comment: `whereas second query shows just the cities with actual time > 100`  ?

Comment: @Squirrel, sorry fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: It should be `180` and not `100`

Comment: @Squirrel Looks like I need to get glasses. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` and `HAVING` filter rows in different timing:

1. `WHERE` kicks in ***before*** `GROUP`
2. `HAVING` kicks in ***after*** `GROUP`

for example lets have this following data :

```
|colA|colB|
|----|----|
|   A| 178|
|   A| 179|
|   A| 180|
|   A| 181|
```

in your query with `WHERE`, it will filter everything <180 which leave us :

```
|colA|colB|
|----|----|
|   A| 178|
|   A| 179|
```

and then start `group` and continue processing.

but in query with `HAVING`, it start to `group` first, then find the `max` :

```
|colA|colB|
|----|----|
|   A| 178|
|   A| 179|
|   A| 180|
|   A| 181|
```

find the max(colB):

```
|colA|max(colB)|
|----|---------|
|   A|      181|
```

and seem like the max(colB) is bigger than 180 which take the whole group of `A` entries out of final result.